# How to use structure in bpftracing scripting

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I have written a func.bt file to use a structure in my kprobe routine.

```c
/* func.bt */

struct FUNC_PARAMS
{
    unsigned int client;
    void * params;
    unsigned int paramsSize;
    unsigned int status;
};

/* This script provides a reasonable estimate of the time spent
 * in processessing ioctls.
 */

BEGIN
```

But, when I run `bpftrace func.bt`, I get the following error:

```
func.bt:34:19-41: ERROR: Unknown struct/union: 'FUNC_PARAMS'
```

Complete script:

```
    struct FUNC_PARAMS
{
    unsigned int client;
    unsigned int paramsSize;
    void *data;
    unsigned int status;
};


kprobe:is_ioctl
{
    @start[comm] = nsecs;
    $temp = arg3;

    @call_count[comm,$temp] = count(); // per process, per ioctl number count of ioctl calls
    $client = ((FUNC_PARAMS *)arg2)->client;
    printf("client: %x \n", $client);  
}

kretprobe:is_ioctl /@start[comm]/
{
    $delta = nsecs - @start[comm];
    delete(@start[comm]);
}
```

Can someone please provide some pointers on how to use this structure correctly?

Comment: Can you include the rest of the script? Also, your structure is named `FUNC_PARAMETERS` but the error message mentions `FUNC_PARAMS`...

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the typo, have updated the synopsis with complete script.

Answer (score 2):

This is because just like in C, you cannot call a struct directly by the name you gave it: `FUNC_PARAMS` is unknown, **you need the `struct` keyword** with it. Replacing:

```c
$client = ((FUNC_PARAMS *)arg2)->client;
```

with

```c
$client = ((struct FUNC_PARAMS *)arg2)->client;
```

seems to solve the problem. In C people sometimes add a `typedef struct FUNC_PARAMS FUNC_PARAMS` to be able to use `FUNC_PARAMS` just like you attempted, but I am not sure bpftrace supports `typedef`s (nor would I recommend [using it](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/coding-style.html#typedefs) anyway).

With the above change, bpftrace goes one step further and complains with:

```
Attaching 2 probes...
cannot attach kprobe, Invalid argument
Error attaching probe: 'kretprobe:is_ioctl'
```

To me, it looks like it cannot find the `is_ioctl` function you want to attach to (and indeed, I see no such functions listed on my system in /proc/kallsyms, or in kernel sources for that matter).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.
is_ioctl is a internal function in my module which is not open source.